# Django collectstatic does not work on nested directories of assets

Tags: django, django-templates

I have an HTML template for my website, which has its own directory structure for  JavaScript, CSS and images. My directory structure is like this:
[ِDirectory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fORms.png)

```
My_Project/
 |-Include/
 |-Lib/
 |-Scripts/
 |-src/
 | |
 | |--static_my_proj/
 | | | ---assets/
 | | | |----app/
 | | | |----demo/
 | | | |----snippets/
 | | | |----vendors/
 | |--templates/
 | |--My_Projects/
 |-static_cdn/
 | |--static_root/
```

There are some static files under the "app," "demo," "snippets" and "vendors" directories and their sub-directories.

My configurations on the "settings.py" are as below:

```
STATICFILES_DIR = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_my_proj")
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn", "static_root")
```

The problem is that when I use "python manage.py collectstatic" command, static files under the sub-directories of "static_my_proj" directory, will not be copied to "static_cdn/static_root/" path. The output on the "static_cdn/static_root" path, only contains "admin" directory and its subsequent "css," "fonts," "img," and "js" directories; there is not any sign that which shows the command ports the statics from the "assets" directory to defined destination.

Any idea?

Comment: I would start by checking directory permissions.

Comment: I checked in Windows and Linux; the output directory has the write permission. Furthermore, the "collectstatic" app creates "admin" directory on the specified output path.

Comment: Does `BASE_DIR` point to `C:\dev\python\My_Project` or `C:\dev\python\My_Project\src`?

Comment: @WillKeeling, it points to `C:\dev\python\My_Project\src`

Answer (score 0):

Your files are in `BASE_DIR/src/static_my_proj`, not `BASE_DIR/static_my_proj`.

Comment: I printed out the path which I set in the settings.py; the path is like this:

C:\dev\python\My_Project\src\static_my_proj

which seems true.